# Find in Files across multiple directories with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-in-files

Is there a way to search within multiple directories in Notepad++ using the Find in Files feature?

I'd like to search the two following locations simultaneously:

```
C:\Views\
H:\Views\
```

I've tried combining them with a comma, a semicolon, and a space, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't support this.  It only supports recursively looking inside a single folder.

Comment: I'm sure I have been able to do this previously, but I can not for the life of me find how to do it again. you can use multiple file filters by seperating with a space, ie *.vb *.vbs

Answer (score 3):

If Notepad++ cannot do that, you can try using [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/). It supports searching within multiple directories and the results are shown in a much more user-friendly way.

[image]

Comment: I second the Sublime suggestion. I'm on the fence about which one I should use as a default editor...

Answer (score 1):

There's a plug-in that might have supported this, but it's no longer compatible with the Unicode version of NP++: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/SearchInFiles/